# iOS 17 URL encoding cause issue in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin.forms app which have a GET Api URL like this

```
sampleurl.com/my-app-data/requests?orderBy=-created_at&related=user,+role&perPage=100
```

This were working fine on Andorid and iOS 16.But after iOS 17, The `"?"` getting changed to `"%"` in the URL like this.

```
sampleurl.com/my-app-data/requests%orderBy=-created_at&related=user,+role&perPage=100
```

which causing error. I guessing that after iOS 17 apple introduced a url parsing behaviour which causing this.How we can tackle this issue?

My code resposible for handling API call is following

```
  var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress };
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;

                    if (receivedMethod == APIMethodConstants.GET)
                    {
                        req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, apiurl);
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", JwtToken);
                        Task<string> task = Task.Run(async () => await Threading(client, req));
                        task.Wait();
                        stringObtained = task.Result;
                        jsonObtained = stringObtained;
                    }

        async Task<string> Threading(HttpClient client, HttpRequestMessage req)
        {
            WebUtility.UrlDecode(req.RequestUri.ToString());
            var resp = await client.SendAsync(req);
            switch (resp.StatusCode)
            {
                  //rest logic
            }
            return stringObtained;
        }
```

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Where do you set assign the value to `apiurl`?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: @Paulw11 I am assigning the URL as it is from viewmodel

Comment: Yes, but is `apiurl` a `String` or a `Uri`?  Whatever is creating the `Uri` is encoding the query string rather than detecting it as a query string. It is better to use [`UriBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder?view=net-8.0) to create your `Uri` and explicitly set the query than to rely on string parsing

Comment: @Paulw11 apiurl is String.

Comment: @Paulw11 How to make this particular url using URLbuildeR?

Comment: You start by initialising the `UriBuilder` with `https://sampleurl.com/my-app-data/requests` and then set its `query` property to `orderBy=-created_at&related=user,+role&perPage=100` or you could use [this constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-uribuilder-ctor(system-string-system-string-system-int32-system-string-system-string))

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried as you suggested. But still in iOS 17 the "?" shows as %.

Comment: @Paulw11             string baseUrl = "sampleurl.com/my-app-data/requests";

            StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder();
            queryString.Append($"orderBy={orderBy}");
            queryString.Append($"&related={related}");
            queryString.Append($"&perPage={perPage}");
            queryString.Append($"&page={page}");
            queryString.Append($"&filter[store_id]={filterStoreId}");
            queryString.Append($"&dateRange={dateRange}");

            string url = $"{baseUrl}?{queryString}";

Comment: @Paulw11 this is how I tried

Comment: That isn't using `UriBuilder`. That is just creating the same string as you had initially in a different way.

Comment: @Paulw11 Oh! I am little confused here. Can you please give me some sample , how to proceed?

Comment: Something like `UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder("https://sampleurl.com/my-app-data/requests"); uri.Query="orderBy=-created_at&related=user,+role&perPage=100"; string requestUrl=uri.Uri;`

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok Thank you. Let me try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257237/discussion-between-paulw11-and-anand).

Comment: We hope that when the solution is found you will post it as an answer!

Comment: @bobwki I added my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried making my URL build using URIBuilder and things and none worked for iOS 17. I changed the HttpClient Implementation into `Managed` from `NsUrlSession`, all my problematic APIs are started working in iOS 17.I think this may be a temporary solution, because changing it into `Managed` may cause performance issues . Will update if any other way found.

[image]